# running install_lib warning: install_lib: 'build\lib' does not exist -- no Python modules to install

Tags: python

```
c:\Python33>python.exe D:\program_python\module_setup\setups.py install
running install
running build
running build_py
running install_lib
**warning: install_lib: 'build\lib' does not exist -- no Python modules to in**


running install_egg_info
Removing c:\Python33\Lib\site-packages\find_elements_of_list-3.3.3-py3.3.eg
o
Writing c:\Python33\Lib\site-packages\find_elements_of_list-3.3.3-py3.3.egg
```

I am getting this error ( is in bold )  can you suggest ( when I am using window 8 -32 bit o/s with python33  as well as  when using Red Hat Linux-6 with  python 2.6 )

```
c:\Python33>update modules list
'update' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Comment: just run the command prompt in administrator and type the location of the module to be installed then run the setup script. It worked for me because I was having the same problem a while ago...

Answer (score 5):

You need to change into the directory of the application and then run the file.

```
c:\Python33>cd D:\program_python\module_setup
c:\Python33>cd D:
D:\program_python\module_setup> C:\Python33\python.exe setup.py install
```

Answer (score 1):

I had to do 2 things:

1. Add `__init__.py` (can be empty) in the setup directory

   ```
   ./main/setup.py
   ./main/setup/__init__.py
   ```
2. Install `cmake` (if it's not installed yet)

   ```
   sudo apt-get install cmake
   ```